# Mount encrypted partition at login for specific user

Tags: windows-7, windows, encryption, truecrypt

I have a partition on my Windows 7 machine that I want to encrypt, but I need it to be decrypted automatically when I log in (and not any other user), and before applications start to run. The partition is NOT the system partition.

The thing is that I want it to automatically mount after login, without asking for a password.

Ubuntu uses ecryptfs to encrypt the user home directory and it automatically mount/decrypts the directory when the user logs in. I want something like that but for Windows 7.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Truecrypt supports command line usage as shown [HERE](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=command-line-usage). The way to accomplish this is using the command:

```
TrueCrypt.exe /l (Drive Letter to be mounted on) /q /v (Volume to be mounted) /k "Path to keyfile if any" /p (Password)
```

A few things to take note:

1. Use EFS to encrypt the batch file to mount the drive.
2. Use EFS to encrypt the keyfile as well.
3. Start the batch file on startup. Follow this [LINK](http://www.jimmah.com/vista/content.aspx?id=2) if you need help overriding UAC for startup programmes on Windows 7.

Caveats:

1. The password is stored in plain text on the computer but not viewable if you are not logged in.
2. By choosing not to require the user to key in the password, you are sacrificing security.